# How to get project path for java swing project

Tags: java, swing

I want to store uploaded file in my project folder itself,so how to get project path for java swing project

Comment: Do you mean the location the application is currently being executed from?  You can use `new File(".")` and use `getPath()` to determine you current execution location...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it by using this...

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following bit of code to identify the location of a class file:

```
private static File findProgramLocation() throws URISyntaxException {
    File file = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not identify program location, found " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        // should be a JAR
        file = file.getParentFile();
    }
    return file;
}
```

It will either return the root folder containing the class files or the folder containing the JAR file if it is packaged.